# How to edit/modify Eclipse IDE properties settings such as Web Project Settings using a java programme or any other methods using java?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin, eclipselink

I am wondering if there any plugins or any way to edit/modify Web project settings in eclipse...right click project --> *Properties*, IDE using a java programme. Is there any java functions or any java related material that let you enable to do modify eclipse IDE settings without manually changing them?
Also anyway to integrate **tomcat** localhost into eclipse IDE using a java programme?
thanks in advance

Comment: Normally you write an Eclipse plug-in to do something like this (these are written in Java). But you will have to do some research to find out how the properties are stored - this often involves reading the appropriate source code.

Comment: @greg-449 is there any links on how to achieve this?